# Excel formula to find the min value when a corresponding value is #

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with times of races I have completed.
I want to be able to show the fastest time for a certain distance.

Please see the spreadsheet [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/liqe2dcig8w5b94/Races.xlsx).

I have highlighted the box I would like the formula in.
I have only been able to find a SUMIF statement, which only selects times based on a distance of 6.25, or a basic MIN function to return the lowest overall. I cannot find how to group these two functions.

The formulas I have tried are in the file to download.

However, I have tried the following

```
=SUMIF(C3:C38, "=6.25", F3:F38) - This gets the sum as expected
=MIN(F3:F38) - This gets the minimum as expected
```

I really do not know how to combine the two statements, the SUMIF is to only way I have found to evaluate one cell, but retrieve data from another
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array function should do the trick. Suppose that:

(1) The distances are stored in range A1:A10.

(2) Your times for each distance are stored in range B1:B10.

(3) The cell that contains the distance you want to find your best time for is cell C1.

The formula would be:

```
=MIN(IF(C1 = A1:A10, B1:B10, ""))
```

What the above formula is doing is returning the set of values in range B1:B10 for which A1:A10 = C1 evaluates to true. Note that the ranges don't have to be adjacent to each other: I could, for instance, store the race times in range B2:B11 and the distances in range X5:X14. The only thing that's important here is that the dimensions of each range are identical (in this case, both have ten rows and one column).

Make sure you hit `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` after the formula's entered into a cell, so that Excel recognizes it's an array formula. If you don't, it'll try to evaluate the expression as a normal formula, and return a #VALUE! error.